# Angular directive $observe jquery widget initialization issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made a directive that wraps freebases jquery search widget. I want the user to be able to change the search language on the fly so I'm using $observe to watch the 'lang' attribute.

The issue is the plugin reinitialized every time the attribute changes but does not end the execution of the previous initialization. When the user selects terms, I'm adding it to an array. If the lang attribute has been modified, the selected term is added for every change to the attribute.

I could just filter the array and only allow items with the same ID to appear once, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

[See plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9aCdNE09mYouwxsatBa2?p=preview)

The directive:

```
directive('suggest', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<input type='text'>",
        replace:true,
        scope:{onSelect:'&'},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            attrs.$observe('lang', function(value) {
                $(element).suggest({
                    lang: value
                })
                .bind("fb-select", function(e, info) { 
                    console.log(info);
                    scope.onSelect({data:info});
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Unbind events bound by a plugin before initializing again.

Comment: Is that as simple as saying .unbind("fb-select")?

Comment: Hmm. It appears so. Thanks dfsq!

Comment: Also, you don't need `$(element)`, just `element` is enough as it's already a jQuery object. And move your `scope.onSelect` inside `scope.$apply(function(){ scope.onSelect({data:info}); });` so that Angular can handle any errors & allow you to deal with it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I get an error: "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'suggest'" when taking 'element' outside of the jQuery holder.